# Actuarial vs. predicted survival comparison

Tags: survival-analysis, survival

I have a set of patients and their actuarial 1- and 5-years survival. I have also used their data with a certain commonly utilised medical score, that calcualtes survival probability for 1- and 5-years (for example 75% and 55% respectively). I'd like to compare both survival rates.

I did calculate the mean survival probability for all patients at 1- and 5-years as the mean of predicted survival probabilities. I then calculated the mean actuarial survival by using 100% if alive at 1 year and 0% if dead at 5 years. I then compared the means of both groups with a t-test.

I have a feeling that what i am doing is grossly incorrect and goes against all rules of statistics, however i have not find any solution of my problem anywhere. Maybe someone can help me? R packages and codes are welcome.

Comment: Is this more a question relating to demographics and statistical analysis than coding? If so, you may be better served by checking in resources related to those fields.

Comment: I don't think this is really about survival analysis since you do not describe a dataset with events and times. You apparently have patients and associated single or paired values for predicted survival given two different methods. A paired t-test should be possible.